# Azure Devops: Add capability to xcode build for push notifications

Tags: xcode, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, onesignal, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm running an azure pipeline to build my .ipa file for iOS Deployment.
Everything is working fine except one detail.

When I'm uploading my app to testflight and run it I got the following message in OneSignal:

> Other Apns 3000 Error
> Error 3000 returned from
> APNs. Ensure "Push Notifications" in Xcode under "Project Target" -> Capabilities are enabled.
> Check the device log in Xcode for more details.

Unfortunately I have not found anything how to enable the capability for push notifications in the pipeline.

My provisioning profile has the capability for push notifications enabled. But this seems not to work. I also have background mode "Remote Notifications" enabled in my info.plist file. This is also not helping.

Here is a part of my pipeline:

```
steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: '*****.p12'
    setUpPartitionIdACLForPrivateKey: false

steps:
- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provisioningProfileLocation: sourceRepository
    provProfileSourceRepository: 'path/path/Profile_*****.mobileprovision'

steps:
- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode clean build'
  inputs:
    actions: 'clean build'
    xcWorkspacePath: path/path/App.xcworkspace
    scheme: App
    packageApp: true
    signingOption: manual
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
    args: '-allowProvisioningUpdates'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/ios'
```

Appended you can find some screenshots:

- [Provisioning Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ1xS.png)
- [OneSignal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ6Cg.png)